# How to segment iterator output based on a predicate?

Tags: python

Is there a built-in way to segment/group iterator output based on a predicate that identifies boundary elements?

For example `segment(range(7), lambda i: i%3 == 1)` should yield an iterator over `[[0, 1], [2,3,4], [5,6]]`.

The following works, but doesn't seem very elegant:

```py
def segment(it, pred):
    def gen():
        acc = []
        for e in it:
            acc.append(e)
            if pred(e):
                yield acc
                acc = []
        if acc:
            yield acc
    return gen()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce:

```
 from functools import reduce
```

The segment function can delegate to reduce, wrapping the predicate with its own `split_by(p)` implementation:

```
def segment(l, p):
    # filter(None, ...) to remove last empty list if such exists
    return filter(None, reduce(split_by(p), l, []))
```

The split by should conform to reduce and split by the predice (creating new segments as needed):

```
def split_by(p):
    def _(l, e):
        if not l:
            return l + [[e]]
        if p(e):
            # end previous segment, and create new segment
            return l[:-1] + [l[-1] + [e]] + [[]]
        # accumulate
        return l[:-1] + [l[-1] + [e]]
    return _
```

Test:

```
> segment(range(7), lambda i: i%3 == 1)
# [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! I'm worried that the reducer code ends up being quite complicated. It also seems to be much slower than the generator approach -- possibly because it ends up creating more lists?

Comment: It is a lot slower. To make it performant you can use list append carefully